# Should I use db.is_modified or compare objects by myself before inserting a new row?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, compare

I'm using SQLAlchemy and the case is that I need to save (insert a new row in other table) old state of object if incoming state of the object from request is different compare to its current state from db.
As I can see, I have two options:

1. I'm comparing two states by myself (using **eq** or something) and if there is a difference, I save old state. If not, I do nothing.
2. I'm using Session and always update my object in db, then I use db.is_modified, and if it's true, I also save the old state.

What way is better and why?

Thank you for your attention.

I am expecting that db.is_modified is better as it seems more accurate but not sure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.